# SQL Group By Aggregate Error

Tags: sql, vba

Got a more complex SQL, but when testing the a much simplified SQL to get to the bottom of an error I still receive

> You tried to excecute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression "datediff("m",0,[StatsDate])" as part of an aggregate
>   function

The SQL I'm testing is:

```
GetSQL = "SELECT datediff(""m"",0,[StatsDate]) as MonthOffset, SUM([Offered]) as OfferedCount From QueueStats Group By MonthOffset"
```

So, I am using the expression `datediff("m",0,[StatsDate])` in the function by referring to it as `MonthOffset` in the expression `Group by MonthOffset`

I'm confused. The expression datediff...... is valid as I've tested that without the Group By.

Comment: "by referring to it as `MonthOffset`" - you should think of it like this: First the SQL engine *executes* the query, and *then* it names the columns with the labels you supply. The labels are meaningless *within* the query.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the alias name in your Group By because the query has to be executed before the field gets named.

Use:

```
Group By datediff("m",0,[StatsDate])
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks braX - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Jet/ACE SQL engine (which underly MS Access, Microsoft Query, Excel VBA Query, DAO/ADO recordsets of workbooks and text files) does allow named aliases to be used but usually in the `SELECT` clause. This is mostly due to SQL's order of operations which differs from other languages that are processed in order of code. However, the very first clause `SELECT` is usually being the last step:

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

For instance, the following is a valid query:

```sql
SELECT DateDiff('m', 0, [StatsDate]) as MonthOffset, 
       SUM([Offered]) as OfferedCount,
       [MonthOffset] + 5 As FiveDaysAhead,
       [OfferedCount] * 2 As DoubleOfferedCount
FROM QueueStats 
GROUP BY DateDiff('m', 0, [StatsDate])
```